how is my Gsap animation not working when deployed

 useGSAP(() => {
    const text = SplitType.create('.ht')
    var char = text.words
   gsap.from(char, {
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: '.ht',
      scroller: 'body',
      toggleActions: "restart reset restart reset",

    },
    opacity: 0,
    yPercent: 100,
    duration: 0.2,
    stagger: 0.0850,
   })


   gsap.from('.about-text', {
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: '.about',
      toggleActions: "restart reset restart reset",
      scroller: 'body',
    },
    
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1.6,
    yPercent: 250,
   })

   gsap.from('.service-text', {
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: '.service-text',
      scroller: 'body',
      toggleActions: "restart reset restart reset",      
    },
    
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1.6,
    yPercent: 250,
   })

   gsap.from('.work-text', {
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: '.work-text',
      scroller: 'body',
      toggleActions: "restart reset restart reset",

      
    },
    
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1.4,
    yPercent: 150,
   })

   gsap.from(".card", {
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: "card",
      scroller: 'body',
    },
    xPercent: -100,
    duration: 0.4,
    stagger: 0.7,
    opacity: 0,
    delay: 1
   })

  });

this animation is only work on local host but not in production i m using nextjs and latest node version. so the animations are of mostly text and i dont have those intense things and still its not working.i have only one plugin that is scroll trigger and not i m using tailwind css  with a component framwork of tailwind . 2animations are not working properly which is of text rise one is .about-text and another is .service-text
